# How to deploy Oracle Forms 10g?

Tags: java, cisco, oracle

En mi caso para poder desplegar Forms de Oracle 10g lo hago en Windows XP mediante Firefox 3.03 utilizando el Jinitiator de Oracle y el JRE.

He intentado hacer esto el Ubuntu 10.04 y 11.10 mediante Wine pero no he podido hacerlo.

¿Es posible hacerlo? y ¿como?

Gracias.

---

In my case in order to deploy Oracle Forms 10g on Windows XP I do with Firefox 3.3 using Oracle Jinitiator and JRE.

I tried this on Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.10 through Wine but I could not do it.

Can this be done? and how?

Thank you.

Comment: Hola Carlos, el idioma oficial de este site es el Inglés. Es necesario que escribas sus preguntas en Inglés.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=491166) on Oracle Forums, Jinitiator ain't supported on flavor of Linux and is a Windows-only product. *Following is an excerpt from it*:

> JInitiator is a Windows only Oracle JVM, enables windows clients to
>   access Oracle Forms applications that are served from the Oracle iAS
>   Enterprise Edition (Forms Services). It is NOT available for any
>   flavor of linux or unix. For linux clients, you can configure the iAS
>   forms services (related formsweb.cfg file) to use Sun JRE (1.5 and
>   higher). This is how I set up my iAS (10.1.2.0.2) EE server for both
>   windows and linux clients to access Oracle Forms. BTW, Jinitiator has
>   nothing to do with the database server. It can be distributed to the
>   windows clients as a separate file (executable), or it will be
>   downloaded from the iAS EE server when the forms services (related
>   forms URL) first accessed from the client.  Hope this proves useful.

---

*Translation by [GoogleTranslate](http://translate.google.com/):*

De acuerdo con [este tema](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=491166) en los foros de Oracle, Jinitiator no es compatible con el sabor de Linux y es un producto sólo para Windows. A continuación * es un extracto de ella *:

> JInitiator es sólo para Windows Oracle JVM, permite a los clientes de
>   Windows para acceder a aplicaciones Oracle Forms que se sirven de la
>   Oracle iAS Enterprise Edition (Forms Services). NO está disponible
>   para cualquier sabor de Linux o Unix. Para los clientes de Linux,
>   puede configurar los servicios de NIC formas (archivo formsweb.cfg
>   relacionada) para utilizar Sun JRE (1.5 y superiores). Así es como
>   puedo configurar mi NIC (10.1.2.0.2) servidor de EA para los clientes
>   Windows y Linux para acceder a Oracle Forms. Por cierto, Jinitiator
>   tiene nada que ver con el servidor de base de datos. Puede ser
>   distribuido a los clientes de Windows como un archivo independiente
>   (ejecutable), o se puede descargar desde el servidor IAS EE cuando los
>   servicios de las formas (URL formas conexas) accede por primera vez
>   desde el cliente. Espero que esto sea de utilidad.